# exception thrown while building the java application using netbeans

Tags: java, exception

Suddenly, while opening and building the application this exception was thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:552)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:374)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.FQN2Files.load(FQN2Files.java:112)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.FQN2Files.<init>(FQN2Files.java:78)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.FQN2Files.forRoot(FQN2Files.java:70)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.JavaParsingContext.<init>(JavaParsingContext.java:110)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.JavaCustomIndexer$2.run(JavaCustomIndexer.java:332)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.JavaCustomIndexer$2.run(JavaCustomIndexer.java:328)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.usages.ClassIndexManager.prepareWriteLock(ClassIndexManager.java:120)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.JavaCustomIndexer.clearFiles(JavaCustomIndexer.java:328)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.JavaCustomIndexer.access$600(JavaCustomIndexer.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.JavaCustomIndexer$Factory.filesDeleted(JavaCustomIndexer.java:883)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Work.delete(RepositoryUpdater.java:2063)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Work.scanFiles(RepositoryUpdater.java:2502)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$FileListWork.getDone(RepositoryUpdater.java:2796)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Work.doTheWork(RepositoryUpdater.java:2582)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Task._run(RepositoryUpdater.java:4681)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Task.run(RepositoryUpdater.java:4618)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callParserResultTask(TaskProcessor.java:618)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(TaskProcessor.java:728)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have searched the meaning of this error but I couldn't understand the solution. Could some body help me quickly and please to make your answer simple to follow.

Comment: The error `Malformed \uxxxx encoding` is because you might be passing an invalid or bad unicode character to some method. Without some code, that's all I can say.

Comment: thnx for helping but how could i find where this passing is?

Comment: My guess is that it's a problem with some path in your project configuration, not in your code - based upon the fact that only the Java library and Netbeans show up in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Via Google, it looks like the problem might be an improperly specified path. If you specify a path like this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\jdoe
```

The `\` character can be interpreted as a bad unicode character, if the following character is a "u". The solution is one of the following:

1. Excape the `\` with another `\` - e.g.:

   `C:\\Documents and Settings\\jdoe`
2. Use `/` instead (**this is probably the better solution**, since it works on all platforms - not just Windows - e.g.:

   `C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe`

Comment: i'm really passing some paths but i'm using the / char and it was working perfectly but this exception where thrown suddenly.. is there any thing could cause this exception..

Comment: Basically, you either have an improperly specified path, or you have a unicode character "\u####" somewhere that is invalid. Because the stack trace doesn't include your code, I might look for weird special characters in your properties or other non-source files, rather than in your source code - same for paths.

Comment: actually i'm not expert in reading the properties files but i've tried and i couldn't as i think find any weird char. could you give my an example.

Comment: You're looking for any `\` characters, or any other characters that are not ASCII printable characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_printable_characters). There are so many possible examples, I'm not sure I can provide a specific one that is very meaningful.