# MissingResourceException but resources aren't missing

Tags: java

I just finished programming a telegram bot inside my IDE on Windows, Netbeans. Runs perfectly with no issues at all. My problem is, when i create a package-for-store in order to upload it inside my own Ubuntu VPS and then I run it (using java -jar PastaBot.jar), console shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name localisation.strings, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1082)
    at utils.LocalisationService.<init>(LocalisationService.java:74)
    at utils.LocalisationService.getInstance(LocalisationService.java:62)
    at pastabot.Pasta.populateDongers(Pasta.java:53)
    at pastabot.Pasta.<init>(Pasta.java:29)
    at pastabot.BotHandler.<init>(BotHandler.java:20)
    at pastabot.TelegramBotJava.main(TelegramBotJava.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:574)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:391)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.<init>(PropertyResourceBundle.java:138)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2687)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1501)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1465)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1419)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1419)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1361)
    ... 7 more
```

I don't get why everything works fine inside my IDE but doesn't even start in my server. i know this is a issue related to my properties files and in most cases, is thrown because strings.properties files are in the wrong path.

Here is my files hierarchy:

[image: file folder structure]

And here is my build.xml file: maybe I'm missing a property inside it but I have no idea on what to do to solve this issue as I'm not really into xml files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Copypastabot" default="default" basedir=".">
<description>Builds, tests, and runs the project Copypastabot.</description>
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

<target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="PastaBot"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
                excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
</target>
```

This is the class LocalisationService I use to get the right locale string, as you can see in the singleton constructor I locate (correctly, I think) localisation files:

```
package utils;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class LocalisationService {
private static LocalisationService instance = null;
private final HashMap<String, String> supportedLanguages = new HashMap<>();

private ResourceBundle english;
private ResourceBundle italian;

private class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);

    }

    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        InputStream utf8in = getParent().getResourceAsStream(name);
        if (utf8in != null) {
            try {
                byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[utf8in.available()];
                utf8in.read(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.length);
                byte[] iso8859Bytes = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(iso8859Bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                try {
                    utf8in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public static LocalisationService getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (LocalisationService.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new LocalisationService();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}


private LocalisationService() {
    CustomClassLoader loader = new CustomClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    english = ResourceBundle.getBundle("localisation.strings", new Locale("en", "US"), loader);
    supportedLanguages.put("en", "English");
    italian = ResourceBundle.getBundle("localisation.strings", new Locale("it", "IT"), loader);
    supportedLanguages.put("it", "Italiano");
}

/**
 * Get a string in default language (en)
 * @param key key of the resource to fetch
 * @return fetched string or error message otherwise
 */
public String getString(String key) {
    String result;
    try {
        result = english.getString(key);
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        result = "String not found";
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Get a string in default language
 * @param key key of the resource to fetch from localisations
 * @param language code key for language (such as "EN" for english)
 * @return fetched string or error message otherwise
 */
public String getString(String key, String language) {
    String result;
    try {
        switch (language.toLowerCase()) {
            case "en":
                result = english.getString(key);
                break;
            case "it":
                result = italian.getString(key);
                break;
            default:
                result = english.getString(key);
                break;
        }
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        result = english.getString(key);
    }

    return result;
}

public HashMap<String, String> getSupportedLanguages() {
    return supportedLanguages;
}

public String getLanguageCodeByName(String language) {
    return supportedLanguages.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getValue().equals(language)).findFirst().get().getKey();
}
}
```

I already searched for solutions but nothing helped me: strings_en.properties is properly located, so I can't get what's going on. I'm stuck on this issue till yesterday and this is driving me mad.

May you guys help me? Thanks :)

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding." see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863301/exception-thrown-while-building-the-java-application-using-netbeans

Comment: I never used any character like \ in my code inside filepaths, the only one specified is the one you can see in LocalisationService pasted below but actually I use dots, not / or \. I used character \ just inside strings as unescape character but this shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: I found that could be my file build.xml doesn't include strings.properties files when I build jar. By the way I'm not sure I'm supposing right... Nor I know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution editing my strings.properties files:
a string like

```
hello\user
```

throws that IllegalArgumentException which causes the program to crash so it won't load nothing (that's why it can't retrieve strings_en.properties).
Instead, better escaping that "\" like this:

```
hello\\user
```

That's because the program tries to encode \user as an hexadecimal value, which is not. A properties file with lots of strings made of non-latin characters, for example one line ascii smileys, could be a real problem to hassle with because \u charaters are commonly used.